# Valid email function. elif statements

Tags: python

I have my function set up I'm just not sure how to write an elif statement that checks if the email has only one domain and if its is a valid domain.

```
def validEmail(address, domains=(".com ", ".net ", ".org ", ".biz ", ".gov ", ".edu ", ".mil ")):
    atLocation = address.index("@")
    atCount = address.count("@")
    len(address)
    periodCount = address.count(".")
    periodLocation = address.index(".")
    if atLocation <= 0:
        return False
    elif periodCount <= 0:
        return False
    elif atCount <= 0:
        return False
    elif periodLocation ==-1:
        return False
    else:
        return True


print(validEmail("me@hotmail.com"))
print(validEmail("@abc.com"))
print(validEmail("me@abc.fat"))
print(validEmail("me@abc."))
print(validEmail("me@abc.def.com"))
```

Comment: Is this an exercise/personal challenge/assignment or is this for something you are making? If it's the former, carry on. If it's the latter, you should be using a library. This wheel has been invented!

Answer (score 0):

To get the domain of the email use rsplit:

```
a_domain = address.rsplit('.', 1)[1]
```

To check if a_doimain is in your list of domains, you can do:

```
valid_domian = a_domain in domains
```